# Redirecting domain to specific port - app on hosting

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I got NodeJS + socket.IO app on hosting, everything is working fine only when I'm connecting via ip_adress:port but when I try to connect by domain name I got 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED' from socket.io, so I guess my app is connecting on wrong port or smoething? How could i change this without setting up a VPS

Comment: You likely need to fix this either at the DNS level or at the app level (not sure which needs fixing).  What port works when you use `ipAddress:port`?  Can you show us the app level code when you're using the domain?  How is your domain configured?  A domain does not contain a port so if you're using a non-standard port, then you still have to put the port in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your domain with your app like this on config file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot "/home/www/DOMAIN_FOLDER"
ServerName www.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com
ServerAlias YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com
ErrorLog "/www/wwwlogs/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com-error_log"
CustomLog "/www/wwwlogs/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com-access_log" combined

ProxyPreserveHost On

#NODE APPLICATION IP AND PORT
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:1234/

#PATH
<Directory "/home/www/DOMAIN_FOLDER">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.html default.htm
</Directory>
```